# To see if entire row of 1 dataframe is present in other dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
col1  col2   col3 
abc   123    @#   
def   456    *&   
pqr   789    ^%
```

df2:

```
col1  col2   col3 
def   456    *&   
pqr   789    ^%   
abc   123    @#   
oup   852    $%
```

I have to check `df1['col1']` with `df2['col1']`, as all the values of `df1['col1']` are present in `df2['col1']` it should return 'True'.

eg: to check `def` of `df1['col1']` with `def` of `df2['col1']` & likewise

I have used `isin`,`eq`,`issubset` functions which is not working

Expected output:
df2:

```
col1  col1_filter    col2   col2_filter  col3  Col3_filter
def     True          456      True        *&   True
pqr                   789                  ^%   
abc                   123                   @#   
oup                   852                   $%
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: This article on [Comparing rows across Dataframes](https://hackersandslackers.com/compare-rows-pandas-dataframes/) could help.

Comment: Is it checking each row or a column. From the example given, itseems you want check if values of one column of a dataframe is present in a column of other dataframe

Comment: `df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])` should work, it will return `True` for all the values of `df2` which are in `df1`.

Comment: First we have to concatenate two tables(dfs).Then take headers of each df separately in 2 separate list. Then use 'df_validation[(list2[i])] = df1[list1[i]].str.strip().isin(df2[list2[i]].str.strip().tolist())'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isin` works fine for my machine as

```
df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)
```

This returns boolean True, if the row of df1 exists in df2. You can also merge the 2 dataframes and then compare.

Comment: Its giving 'False' as the col values are shuffled,& also can 'isin' work to check to traverse 1 value from the column (like 'DSL') to another col of df?

Comment: I did not understand what do you want to say. Please be elaborate. Also, do you want to check for all columns separately? Like, if col1 and col3 exist in df2, but col2 doesn't, then it should return True False True?

Comment: yes...I want True or False value for each col.

Comment: You can add a column to both dataframes, named ID, containing row number. Merge the dataframes now, and do l1 = pd.Series(df.col11.isin(df.col21)) where col11 is col1 of df1 and col21 is col1 of df2. In the next line, do df['Same1'] = l1. This will add a column in the merged dataframe, showing True or False, based on if col11 value exists in col21

Comment: You can do similar for the rest of the columns

Comment: Its giving 'False' as the values are shuffled. eg: if index 1 of col1 is abc then in other col2 index 4 is 'abc' and so on....thatz why isin is not working

Comment: This is where isin() function comes handy. I tried my code with the exact dataframe you posted. isin() works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']= ['abc','bcd','def']
df['col2']= ['5','6','7']
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['col1']= ['asa','bcd','sa']
df1['col2']= ['8','6','9']

df = df[df==df1] #main code to compare the rows
print(df.head())
```

tried to implement the same thing with my code , this solution can help you

Comment: df = df[df==df1] these cant be used it will work for only equal length data frames

Comment: rows are not equal